# How can I control the cursor's position of Editor view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a small application that has an Editor on it. The application detects the '~' character user enters and converts it to the '|' character by using the Editor's TextChanged event and C# string.Replace() method.

For the last word which is being typed in the Editor, if it contains '~' character, the app converts that '~' character to '|' character, and the cursor thereafter moves beyond the last character of the word. It is fine.

In the Editor, if user taps the Editor at the end or inside of any word  whose position is located **prior to** the last word in the Editor, and if the user types in a '~', the application detects and converts it to '|' character. However, the cursor then moves beyond the last word in the Editor. That is not what I expect.

I'd like the cursor keeps its position at the end or inside of the word that is lately modified rather than beyond the last word in the Editor. How can I fix do that? Thanks in advance.

I am using Xamarin.Forms version 2.3.0.x and codes are written in the PCL project of the app solution. I am using VS 2015.